# How to make from xamarin.forms 4.3 identical to СarouselPage?

Tags: xamarin.forms

The documentation says that I should use the page carousel for the place, this is a carousel view. But I do not understand how to do this.
I have three completely different pages. If earlier I could do like this. look how easy it is.

```
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test.Views"     
       x:Class="test.Corusel">
    <CarouselPage.Children>
            <local:Page1></local:Page1>
            <local:Page2></local:Page2>
    </CarouselPage.Children>
```

Now, when I try to make a look identical to the CarouselPage, I just have a white screen.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test.Views"     
       x:Class="test.Corusel">
<CarouselView>
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
               <local:View1></local:View1>
               <local:View2></local:View2>  
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
</ContentPage>
```

People tell me that there should be an itemSource. Without itemSource, content will not be displayed. But as I understand it, itemSource does not allow you to make different layouts for data.

I don’t understand how I can make a copy of СarouselPage from СarouselView (or CollectionView) if:

1. My pages have different layouts!
2. To load content into different layouts, I use different functions!

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge what you are looking for is the `DataTemplateSelector`

Create a subclass of Selector with properties that hold the templates:

```
 public class PersonDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
 {
       public DataTemplate ValidTemplate { get; set; }
       public DataTemplate InvalidTemplate { get; set; }

     protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate (object item, BindableObject container)
     { 
             return ((Person)item).DateOfBirth.Year >= 1980 ? ValidTemplate : InvalidTemplate;
     }
   }
```

Add them to your resources:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="validPersonTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
               ...
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="invalidPersonTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
               ...
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:PersonDataTemplateSelector x:Key="personDataTemplateSelector"
            ValidTemplate="{StaticResource validPersonTemplate}"
            InvalidTemplate="{StaticResource invalidPersonTemplate}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
```

Use them:

```
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource personDataTemplateSelector}"
```

For more information check the microsoft documents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector